# Redirect/Change the Hyperlink using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I have a page with a iframe in it. On the main page there is a menu. On click of a menu item page gets loaded in to the iframe. There are many hyperlink in the loaded page. Now those hyperlinks should be opened in the same iframe.

When some one clicks the hyperlink it will load a page in the iframe.
My question is :
instead of loading the page which is defined in the src="" of hyperlink I want a different page to load after the user clicks the hyperlink.

I need the java script to change the src="" parameter.

I am working in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  need to call a javascript function on click of hyperlink and in that javascript function you need to redirect to different url, return false in onclick event of hyperlink

```
  <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" onClick="openURL();return false;">open</a>  

  <script>
         function openURL(){
              window.location.href="http://google.com";
         }
  </script>
```

Comment: Sorry if i have made the question confusing. I don't want the hyperlink to change. when a user clicks the hyperlink javascript will say load another page.Example. <a herf="test.php" >open</a>. When user click the open link it will not open test.php but will load tree.php.

Comment: Why you are not giving loadtree.php directly in hyperlink??

Comment: I just want to hide the hyperlink where I am redirecting the page to.

Comment: @kash please see my edit as per your problem description

Comment: <html>
<script>
         function openURL(){
              window.location.href="http://google.com";
         }
  </script> 
<body>
 <a href="http://www.google.com" target="main" onClick="openURL();return false;">Open</a>
 
<div >
    <iframe name="main" id="main" src="" frameborder="0" width="99%" height="590"><FONT FACE=ARIAL SIZE=3 COLOR="RED">Your Browser doesn't Support Required Component.</FONT></iframe>
</div>    
</body>
</html>     This is the code which I am talking. I want google.com to open in the "main" frame